# WDS on windows server 2012 R2 DNS and DHCP problems

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v, dhcp, wds

**Intro:**
I have 1 server with an onboard NIC and 1 usb NIC, the onboard NIC is for `network 1` (my home network) and the usb NIC is for `network 2` (my virtual network) so they are separated and do not interfere with each other.

**Virtual program:**
I use `Hyper-V` for all of my virtual machines and I have my usb NIC set as a virtual network and selected in `Hyper-V` which NIC it needed to use so that my networks are separated.

**What i have done:**
I installed `Windows Server 2012 R2` on my virtual machine, I checked my own computer and looked which ip my computer got (`network 1`) and I checked what IP my virtual server got (`network 2`) my virtual server had a different IP, so I assigned a static IP `192.168.2.2` and I installed my `Active Directory`, `DNS` and `DHCP`. Then I got this message:

> A delegation for this DNS server cannot be created because the authoritative parent zone cannot be found or it does not run Windows DNS server

I searched but it didn't made sense because the AD and the DNS are on the same server and on the same network but I have seen that most people say do not bother it because it is on the same server. For some reason my DHCP won't give IP addresses, god knows why, and I can not do a network boot because of that. It really is annoying me

**Problem:**
I can't get `WDS` working and I don't have a single clue anymore where to look or how to find out. It is my first time with WDS and I have searched multiple sites and videos for help or how to do it but without luck.

Could it be that it has to do with my other network?!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What does the PXE client say when it tries to network boot?

Thanks!

Comment: It is best to keep the services as separated as possible because if one is compromised then the rest are on the same machine, easy pickings. If they are on separate machines then if one is compromised they would have to compromise each other one individually. It is the same for system reliability, if the one machine that runs everything fails then everything fails. If you distribute the workload then there would be no single point of failure. If it is just a test network then it should be safe to run everything off of the one server.

Comment: Also did you install all of them at the same time, or some specific order?
I generally start from a fresh install then install ADDS (as a DC) then run the setup wizard for ADDS, it will install and config DNS as needed. after that has finished then I install WDS and DHCP. WDS will link up with ADDS. Configure the DHCP server to distribute IPs and set WDS to use the onboard DHCP server (properties dialog of WDS system).

Comment: If you want just WDS then you can run it without ADDS and DNS. It runs purely from DHCP and the WDS module.

Comment: Hello elliot, yes i did a fresh install and first began with ADDS and when i did that i got that error message why i don't know because i'm on a seperate network. this is still a test enviroment so i like to keep it on 1 system. when i try to PXE boot it says: no dhcp or proxydhcp offers were received. this i don't get because they are on the same network i have set the DHCP pool and set the dhcp pool is set from 192.168.2.3 to 192.168.2.10. i can see on the server and on the client that the nics are glowing and blinking 1 green and 1 orange

Comment: i will also try an standalone server so i can look if i do anything wrong, **Note:** my DHCP does have the option 60 PXE, just saying

Comment: But WDS needs DNS it everyone says it, how can it work without DNS?

Comment: WDS does not need DNS, AD DS needs DNS. WDS is a framework that sits on top of PXE. PXE stands for Preboot eXecution Environment. PXE is started from DHCP and uses TFTP to get the initial files to the client. The client then executes the transfers files. WDS is part of the initial files. It then uses a protocol like SMB (in the case of Windows) to transfer the rest of the files (TFTP is really slow). WDS really kicks in after the system is loaded, it facilitates the transfer application and capture of system images. WDS can use a DNS setup but it can also use an ip setup.

Comment: If it uses an ip set up you will most likely have to type the ip address or authentication in for the PXE client t booted system to interact with the server. Based on what you said I am going to guess that your USB NIC is causing the issue. Use only one nic and set up virtual NICs. You can do that in the networking center of hyper-v. If you have physical devices that need to communicate with the virtual equipment then use VLANs to separate the traffic. You can still keep it to one NIC with that config. If that is too advanced then try subnetting.

Comment: Did you activate/enable the DHCP scope on your DHCP server? Also is it authoritative?

Comment: yes i have activated the scope, it is working now after i removed my default gateway now my client boots up from network but won't initiate the install it says: **Windows Setup** WdsClient: an error has occured while contacting Windows Deployment Service-server. Check if the server is operational or if the needed ports are open in the server's firewall. Servername [WDSSERVER.stef.local], IP-address [10.1.10.2]  do you have a clue what is going on i looked at my server it is running, looked at my firewall i can not change any settings about WDS thanks in advance

Comment: It appears that you are still using an ADDS environment. I would recommend building only with the basics rebuild your environment using only DHCP and WDS. After you get that working then add ADDS.

Comment: Now i have set up a new enviroment with only DHCP and WDS but yet again i stall at the same point. i have everything configured on my DHCP and yet it won't work!!! It's really getting frustrating now! because i want it to work so badly ;( and i still get the same error message **Windows Setup** WdsClient: an error has occured while contacting Windows Deployment Service-server. Check if the server is operational or if the needed ports are open in the server's firewall. Servername [WDSserver-Stef-Standalone], IP-address [20.2.20.3]

Comment: But Elliot Labs, it should not be a driver issue from the client?

Comment: PXE is built into the BIOS/UEFI. It will not be a driver issue. I am thinking that it is a network issue. Make a new virtual network and set it to private. Set the two VMs to that network and see if it will network boot properly. Make sure that you remove that USB Ethernet adapter as I think it might be playing you wrong. When you get that WDS error, is that during the PXE phase or during the PE phase?

Comment: Also, to double check, on the DHCP tab of the WDS properties, you have both check boxes checked?

Comment: yes, i even checked both (bootp and a another (forgot the name of the first one))

Comment: mmm, ok if it was the usb nic why can i network boot it till the install? and if it is the usb nic i don't have a nic card laying around in the building the server only has 1 ethernet port

Comment: u want me to mail me the virtualbox? it does take a lot of time yes, if that is what you want then okay!

Comment: Do you have any preferences?

Comment: @ElliotLabs i have found the solution, it was inside hyper-v i had selected the normal network adapter, so i changed it to legacy and it works! thank you soooo much for thinking with me!

Comment: That is amazing to hear. If you could Post the answer to your solution as an answer you could easily help other people. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked your Hyper-v settings? it could be you use the normal network adapter. You should be using the Legacy Network Adapter.
Here is the link for the answer: [Hyper-V network adapter differences](http://www.virtualizationadmin.com/blogs/lowe/news/hyper-v-network-adapter-differences-192.html)
 read the last 2 paragraph's that will explain a lot. 
 these are the steps to do it: go to your VM > Settings > Add Hardware then select Legacy Network Adapter then click on Add, this will add the legacy network adapter now you can assign the right NIC to the network adapter i did remove the other network adapter so i won't make any mistake by choosing the wrong network adapter.

Hope this will help you and anyone else.